# App not working full screen? Both on the emulator and on the phone

Tags: android

**my manifest codes and theme code. Not working fullsecreen?**
App not working full screen? Both on the emulator and on the phone.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        android:name=".Activity.acilis"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
</application>
</manifest>
```

My theme codes

```
<style name="Theme.MyApplication" forceDarkAllowed="false" 
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<style name="Theme.MyApplication.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.MyApplication.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" 
/>
<style name="Theme.MyApplication.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

please help :)

Comment: Share the out-put image

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the code for full screen inside java file

above the setcontentview() , you have to code like this:

```html
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        hideSystemUI();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            getWindow().getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_expand_image);
```

code for hideSystemUI();

```html
 private void hideSystemUI() {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }
```

Comment: now button navigation and admob are not working. How can I make a solution?

Comment: button navigation and adMob not working,where did i go wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


ImageButton ara;
public static String vpKonum="altin";
private void hideSystemUI() {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
}

@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(@NonNull @NotNull 
        InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });


    AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);




    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNav.setItemIconTintList(null);
    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

    //I added this if statement to keep the selected fragment when rotating the 
    device
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        
   
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new home()).commit();
    }

    hideSystemUI();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        getWindow().getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ara = findViewById(R.id.ara);

    ara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Ara.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

  }

  private final BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener 
 navListener 
    =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        selectedFragment = new home();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_favorites:
                        selectedFragment = new ek0();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_search:
                        selectedFragment = new ek1();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_user:
                        selectedFragment = new ek2();
                        break;

                }
                assert selectedFragment != null;
                
  
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        selectedFragment).commit();
                return true;
            }
        };
```